# SailsJS automigration enabled: alter, not updating tables

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am trying to update(add a column) my tables according to my model. Rails has db:migrate and I suppose Sails's auto-migration does the same thing. With `migrate: 'alter'` set inside `modulel.exports.models`, and after lifting Sails, there was no console message where it tries to migrate to the database and indeed, the table columns were not updated. Auto-migration failed.

I am currently using compose.io's mongodb. Any insights would help. Thanks.

Comment: do you get an error message?

Comment: Nope. Just a line, Express middleware for passport followed by infos which draws the sail and finally a debug log which explains:


`debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Tue Mar 03 2015 10:41:53 GMT+0800 (SGT)
debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 1337
debug: --------------------------------------------------------`

Comment: does migrate: 'drop' work?

Comment: I never tried drop, but does drop clear all my data(rows)? I don't want to wipe all my rows everytime there is a migration.